# How to pass value from one html page to another in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I know this question ask many times but my question is something different.
I have 3 html pages like `apply.html`, `personal_info.html`, `resume info.html`.

1. In apply.html page:-
         I use one LinkedIn button for LinkedIn-login. when user click on that button and  filling login information, it fetch user data from LinkedIn. And show it on same page(apply.html).
2. In personal_info.html:-
   I need to show this personal information in respective `TextField` which we fetch from LinkdIn.
3. In Resume_info.html:-
   Here I need to show Career information which we fetch on apply.html page using LinkedIn.

I don't understand how to do this?  I am very new on `Html,JavaScript`.
Here is my code for your reference.

Apply.html  where I fetch LinkedIn Date

```
<html>
<head>    
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function loadData() {
IN.API.Profile("me")
.fields(["id", "firstName", "lastName", "pictureUrl","headline","industry","location:(name)","positions:(title)","emailAddress"])
  .result(function(result) {
  profile = result.values[0];
  profHTML = "<p><a href=\"" + profile.publicProfileUrl + "\">";
  profHTML += "<img class=img_border align=\"left\" src=\"" + profile.pictureUrl + "\"></a>";      
  profHTML += "<a href=\"" + profile.publicProfileUrl + "\">";
  profHTML += "<h2 class=myname>" + profile.firstName + " " + profile.lastName + "</a> </h2>";
  profHTML += "<span class=myheadline>" + profile.headline + "</span>";
  profHTML += "<h3>" + profile.industry + "</h3>";
  profHTML += "<h3>" + profile.location.name + "</h3>";
  profHTML += "<h3>" + profile.positions.values[0].title + "</h3>";
  profHTML += "<h3>" + profile.positions.values[1].title + "</h3>";
  profHTML += "<h3>" + profile.emailAddress + "</h3>";
 $("#profiles").html(profHTML);
  });
 } 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="IN/Login" data-onAuth="loadData"></script>
<div id="profiles"></div>
<div id="profiles1"></div> 
</body>
```

personal_Info.html where I need to show LinkedIn data.

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<section>
<div class="results"> 
 <div class="results-head">
  Personal Info
  <div class="pagecount">1/6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="job-des">
   <div class="row">
     <input name="textfield2" type="text" id="textfield1" value="First Name"  class="input-field" onblur="if (this.value == '')">
   </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield2" value="Last Name" class="input-field"> 
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield3" value="Street Address" class="input-field"> 
  </div>
   <div class="row">
    <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield4" value="City" class="input-field"> 
  </div>
   <div class="row">
   <select name="select2" id="select2" class="input_list2">
      <option value="">  Country  </option>
    </select>
  </div>
   <div class="row">
    <select name="select2" id="select3" class="input_list2">
      <option>State</option>
    </select>
  </div>
   <div class="row">
     <select name="select2" id="select4" class="input_list2">
      <option>Region</option>
    </select>
  </div>
   <div class="row">
    <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield5" value="Zip/Postal Code" class="input-field"> 
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield6" value="Email Address" class="input-field"> 
  </div>
   <div class="row">
   <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" checked align="bottom"> 
   Authorization to work in U.S.
  </div>



  </div>


</div>
<div class="input-btn-panel">
  <div class="input-btn-wrap"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Next" class="blue-btn" onClick="updateTxt()"></div>

 <div id="profiles"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Please give me some hint. I don't understand how to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can store some information in cookies?

Comment: Cookies.Cookies.Cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the HTML5 local storage.  It lets you tell the browser to save data on the user's machine.  (There's also *session storage*, valid only for the current session.)

**Save (in Apply.html)**

```
IN.API.Profile("me")
.fields(["id", "firstName", "lastName", "pictureUrl","headline","industry","location:(name)","positions:(title)","emailAddress"])
  .result(function(result) {
      profile = result.values[0];

      // save all keys to local storage
      for (f in profile) localStorage[f] = fields[f];

      // more stuff ...
  });
```

**Retrieve (in personal_Info.html)**

```
// retrieve first name from local storage
var firstName = localStorage["firstName"];
if (firstName !== undefined) {
    $("#textfield1").attr(value, firstName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i have some question....will it save all field in local storage? where i need to add for loop in my function? and how to check whether all field add correctly or not?

Comment: @SandipArmal yes, this line loops through the fields and adds them: `for (f in fields) localStorage[f] = fields[f];`.  Just use `localStorage["firstName"] === undefined` to check if the field was added correctly.

Comment: ok i use your code like this... var fields =  IN.API.Profile("me")
 for (f in fields) localStorage[f] = fields[f];  Then i accept all value from html.... but when i am trying to show added value it doesn't show anything.... will you edit your answer more details with the help of my code... I really appreciate you...

Comment: @SandipArmal I just realized I made a mistake in the *apply.html* logic, that's probably why it wasn't working for you.  Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use HTML5 session storage.
Check this [link](http://playground.html5rocks.com/#sessionstorage).

Just dig around on HTML5 session storage and you will find a lot of examples.